# Calculating the differences of grouped rows on a tablix

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a report structure like this:

[image: The structure of my tablix]
[image: The grouping outline]

And the output of this report is like this.

[image: The output]

But I also want a third table which contains the differences of the first week and the last week.

Is there a way to do this in SSRS?

[image: desired table]

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this but I guess you would have an identical table without the top level group. Though you could place an extra column there without a group and call it differences. In the data set properties sort by week of the year, then in the data box you would have the expression:

```
=first(Fields!Data.Value) - last(Fields!Data.Value)
```

Comment: Believe it or not this is EXACTLY what I needed. I had two grouped rows I needed to do a calculation on. These values were the same column but different rows and I only had two so first and last worked!

Answer (score 0):

If no other answers work, I would just try to do the aggregation in your query because SSRS isn't as flexible as most would like when it comes to separate tables/matrices, grouping and aggregation.  If you need help with that query please put a comment below and I'll help out.